# Why legend box size increases when I zoom plot in r?

Tags: r, plot, statistics, legend

When I use `legend` command in r, the size of the legend box is true, but when I zoom plot, the size of the legend box increases with a large scale. Are there any options to set height and width of legend box size such that when I zoom plot, legend box size changes with the same scale?

code:

```
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))

legend("topright", legend = c("RPs", "APs", "Real position", "Estimation position"),
   pch = c(4,17,21,21), col = c("black","green","blue", "red"), cex = 0.65,
   pt.cex=1,text.font = 4)
```

I use`windows(x,y)` before of `plot` command to resolve it. But I think it's not a good way. is there another way?